# Datatype conversion while using read_sql in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am using read_sql_table() to fetch a data from sql to python where the data after import looks like:

```
column1       column2          column3
1.0            868.0            76225.0
0.0            2767.0           2763.0
```

When I read this table into a dataframe it's getting converted to  float. Since I need those columns as integer, I'm using:

`df['column2']=df['column2'].fillna(0).astype('int')`. (Using fillna(0) as there are Nan values)

But I also want to convert all the zeroes (due to fillna(0)) back to `NaN`.

If I try `df['column2'].replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)`, this not only converts the `zeroes to Nan`, but also `integer back to float`.

Any help on how to convert float to integer using read_sql_table, without changing `Nan` to 0.

Thanks !!

Comment: by default `NaN` is a float , hence it converts the dtype to float , you might want to consider a [Nullable Integer datatype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/user_guide/integer_na.html) as a dtype as integer with NaN present

Comment: I get `TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent object to int64` when I try `df['column2'].fillna(0).astype('Int64')` @anky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From pandas version `0.24.0`, an `Int64` datatype is made available which can be used to store `NaN`s in an integer array.

So, you can use
`df['column2'] = df['column2'].astype('Int64')`

This will convert all the `float` values to `int` while keeping the `NaN`s intact.

---

References:

[Official pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support)